# Making JavaScript load more numbers?

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, mathematical-optimization

I have а simple JavaScript code that generates an array of all numbers between 0 and 10, then again from 0 to 10. For example:

1+2=
4+5=
3+8=
4+5=

Random  all 121 numbers.
Check the code for better understanding.
This part is hopefully working.

The code:

```js
 arr = [];
 var lastArr = [];



while(lastArr.length<121){
    arr.push('<br>'+Math.round(Math.random() * 10)+'+'+Math.round(Math.random() * 10)+'=');
lastArr=removeDuplicates(arr);
  
}
  
document.getElementById('plus').innerHTML=(lastArr.join(' '));


 
function removeDuplicates(arr){
    let unique_array = []
    for(let i = 0;i < arr.length; i++){
        if(unique_array.indexOf(arr[i]) == -1){
            unique_array.push(arr[i])
        }
    }
    return unique_array
}
```

```html
<html>
<p id='plus'></p>
</html>
```

**The problem:**

I want to make the same thing with the numbers to 100. Next step if it's done is to make to 1000 and next, but let's get back to the problem. The page stops responding(probably infinity loop) and nothing displays.

Below is the problematic code:

```
//DON'T RUN! PAGE CRASHES
arr = [];
 var lastArr = [];

while(lastArr.length<(101*101)){
    arr.push('<br>'+Math.round(Math.random() * 10)+'+'+Math.round(Math.random() * 10)+'=');
lastArr=removeDuplicates(arr);

}

document.getElementById('plus').innerHTML=(lastArr.join(' '));

function removeDuplicates(arr){
    let unique_array = []
    for(let i = 0;i < arr.length; i++){
        if(unique_array.indexOf(arr[i]) == -1){
            unique_array.push(arr[i])
        }
    }
    return unique_array
}

//HTML

<p id='plus'></p>
```

**Second problem:**

I want to make top clean the array from duplicating math results:

*e.x.*

1+0=

0+1=

*e.x.2*

2+1=

1+2=

In the array should left only the first generated(no matter which).

Comment: *"probably infinity loop"* - Why not debug to confirm this?  Take a look at your browser's debugging tools.  You can step through the code, line by line, as it executes.  When doing this you can observe the runtime values and behavior of the code and observe specifically where it deviates from what you expect.  When you debug, where does that deviation first happen?

Comment: This is an extremely inefficient way of generating the final array. You're trying to generate all permutations of `a + b` by chance. Also, you filter the entire array (of up to 10,000 elements) for unique values on every loop when you only need to filter using the last added value since you know all the previous values are unique (so you can conditionally push the new random element rather than call *removeDuplicates*).

Comment: Look up shuffle algorithms.  A Fisher-Yates shuffle would easily be able to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're changing your `while` loop to `lastArr.length<(101*101)`, which runs over 10,000 times. Your code crashes as a result.

To make use of numbers up to `1000`, all you have to do is change the two `(Math.random() * 10)` to `(Math.random() * 100)`, as can be seen in the following example:

```js
arr = [];
var lastArr = [];

while (lastArr.length < (121)) {
  arr.push('<br>' + Math.round(Math.random() * 100) + '+' + Math.round(Math.random() * 100) + '=');
  lastArr = removeDuplicates(arr);
}

document.getElementById('plus').innerHTML = (lastArr.join(' '));

function removeDuplicates(arr) {
  let unique_array = []
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (unique_array.indexOf(arr[i]) == -1) {
      unique_array.push(arr[i])
    }
  }
  return unique_array
}
```

```html
<p id='plus'></p>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: works well, however, how does it remove "inverted" equations? i.e. 0+1 and 1+0 ?